# Dynamic Func<> for Dapper query map

Tags: c#, reflection, dapper

I'm attempting to dynamically generate and execute the sql for [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) with the aim to simply pass in a type and the sql is generated and executed dynamically.

Example classes:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

Will effectively run the following:

```
// sql: "SELECT User.UserId, Address.UserId, Address.PostCode FROM User LEFT JOIN Address ON Address.User = User.UserId"... // auto generated from 'User' type including join to 'Address';

connection.Query<User, Address, User>(sql, /*** map argument needs to be dynamic Func<> ***/);
```

So given these types `User` & `Address` which are only known at runtime, how can I generate the appropriate delegate `Func<User, Address, User>` to pass to the `map` argument?

```
Func<User, Address, User> map = (u, a) => {
    u.Address = a;
    return u;
}
```

The [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738499/create-dynamic-funct-tresult-from-object) I have seen for creating a `Func<>` using reflection assume the types are known, in my case they aren't so the type arguments vary (Func<,> / Func<,,> / Func<,,,> etc).

Any help appreciated.  I'll keep working through examples using expressions to see if anything sticks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21731667/1264882

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I've gotten. I tried to clone the Dapper repo to dig through how the Query() method works, but I'm using an older version of Visual Studio.

```
public static class DynamicFuncHelper
{
    public static Delegate CreateFunc(Type type1, Type type2)
    {
        Type funcType = typeof(Func<,,>).MakeGenericType(type1, type2, type1);
        MethodInfo method =
            typeof(DynamicFuncHelper<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(type1, type2)
            .GetMethod("SetAddressProperty",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
            );
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, method);
    }
}

public static class DynamicFuncHelper<T,U> 
    where T : class 
    where U : class
{
    public static T SetAddressProperty(T obj1, U obj2)
    {
        obj1.GetType().InvokeMember("Address",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            Type.DefaultBinder, obj1, new[] { obj2 });
        return obj1;
    }
}
```

Passed this unit test

```
[TestClass]
public class DynamicFuncTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDynamicMapper()
    {
        var actualUser = new User { UserId = 1 };
        var actualAddress = new Address { PostCode = "12345", UserId = 1 };
        var testSetAddress = DynamicFuncHelper.CreateFunc(typeof(User), typeof(Address));
        var delegateResult = testSetAddress.DynamicInvoke(actualUser, actualAddress);
        Assert.AreEqual(actualUser, delegateResult, "Delegate result was not actualUser");
        Assert.AreEqual(actualAddress, actualUser.Address, "User address was not expected address");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.  That looks promising but I'm still stuck with the fact that there could be any number of type arguments for `Func`.  I've found [this library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Mapper/) that appears to solve the problem - I may just end up pulling that in to solve the map argument.