# How to build Func<> dynamically?

Tags: c#, expression

Can I build Func<> with dynamically type.
What I mean is is there any way to build func like below:

```
Func<typeof(myclass),bool> f=..........
```

or

```
Type myType;
Func<myType,bool> f=............
```

In my project, I need to build expression base on the the class below:

```
class Variable{
  public Type VarType{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public object Value{get;set;}
}
```

The method below build expression base on the value property, if value is null, I should build a lambdeexpression, if value is not null I should build a constantexpression

```
Expression ToExpression(Variable variable){
  if(variable == null){
     // return constantexpression
  }else{
    string[] strs = variable.Name.split(new char[1] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(variable.VarType, strs[0])
    MemberExpression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, strs[1]);
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(someValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<variable.VarType, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant), parameter);
  }
}
```

But now, it seem the `Expression.Lambda<Func<variable.VarType, bool>>` is wrong.

So my question is there any way to build the func like

```
Func<typeof(myclass),bool> f=..........
```

Comment: Yes. However we need more details on what you're trying to do - having created the `Func`, you won't be able to reference it directly in your code: it will either have to be a `Delegate` or a `Func<object, bool>` or similar.

Comment: Have a look at expression-trees for example. What do you need the func for? How do you want to use it?

Comment: `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is also able to easily do this. However we can't give you exact code based on your question alone.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738499/create-dynamic-funct-tresult-from-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Dynamic Func<T, TResult> from Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738499/create-dynamic-funct-tresult-from-object)

Comment: This sounds like you need to put the method inside the class instead of overcomplicating thing. Or if you don't have access to it you are looking at extensions

Comment: The duplicate **might** solve OPs problem, however chances are high OP is **actually** interested in something different and has some very specific problem - which we don´t know.

Comment: Generics should help here with building the expression tree

Comment: As you know your types only at runtime you can´t create a statically typed func, which would need the **compiler** to infer that type. So just use the [non-generic `Expression.Lambda`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Lambda_System_Type_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Linq_Expressions_ParameterExpression__) instead